# svg or png for better performance in PIXI.js and WebGL?

Tags: performance, svg, png, webgl, pixi.js

my question may seems not new, but as far as I searched for days I couldn't find my answer.

I'm trying to make a webpage with PIXI.js which uses webGL.
My webpage is mouse movement parallax, I mean all the movements an object can have is few pixels when the user moves his/her mouse pointer.

**Now my problem: I have some simple images and i don't know to use svg or png.**

My images are like these:

- https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj-BeFYyTnRzhTBSVEXXeJ2c-O7V
- https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj-BeFYyTnRzhTFeTzJLrWaq_VFh
- https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj-BeFYyTnRzhTIa9lAaS9dKX1DL

**I want to make my webpage as smooth as possible and I don't know to use png or svg**. I searched a lot, some says it depends on the png and svg, in my case my svgs won't be too complex but some says because svg use CPU and the WebGL use GPU using them both, cause lack of performance, and also some says which using svg in PIXI makes no difference than the png because PIXI makes texure from them and there won't be any deference...

I'm new to webGL and Pixi so now with these answers I became confused, by the way, for my case the images size is not mattered, I only wanted as much smoothness as possible.

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: also I would appreciate you, giving me some articles or books or ... for optimizing a webpage for better smoothness and performance ... I like to learn how to code in JavaScript, html and... to make use of less CPU and other resources, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference for **runtime** performance, the SVGs will be rasterized into textures either way. However during **initialization** where the browser neeeds to rasterize the SVGs to create a texture from them there might be a significant performance penalty depending on how complex your SVGs are.

However since you're developing for the web aforementioned penalty is easily offset by the fact that you're loading the SVGs from a server which introduces way more latency than rasterizing the SVG will, even more so if you consider the size difference between a rasterized PNG and a SVG(assuming you're not planning to create tiny textures from them).

So final verdict, go with SVG, its lossless and small aswell as resizable and editable from within client code. It also saves you from exporting your source assets to PNG everytime you change something.

Comment: thanks a lot man, I think it answered my question. thanks a lot.